# Memcache expiry time 1 hour out using AWS Elasticache and Enyim memcached client

Tags: c#, memcached, amazon-elasticache, enyim

I'm trying to test my AWS Elasticache nodes using Memcached and the Enyim client, however for some reason the expiry time seems to be out by 1 hour.

I've added data using this code:

```
_client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "testkey", "test", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
```

Then I'm attempting to retrieve the data using

```
var data = _client.Get<string>("testkey");
```

However this never retrieves the data.  If however I change the expiry to 61 minutes from now, it will store the data for 1 minute.  I've tried this with TimeSpan rather than DateTime.Now but get the same issue.

I've also outputted `DateTime.Now` value which is correct, and my AWS region is EU-West which is in the same timezone as the outputted `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 2):

It would be safer to use:

```
_client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "testkey", "test", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));
```

This way, you won't have any dependencies to the DateTime and UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.  I didn't really take UTC into account, and that's what the Elasticache instances use.  Therefore to fix my issue I just need to use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now`